# Add a dummy variable to a SAS data set which doesn't depend on existing data

Tags: sas

I am really having trouble finding the answer to the following simple question. Suppose I have an existing data set with one column of 100 observations, and I want to **add** a variable which has the value 0 in rows 1-50, and 1 in rows 51-100. How can I do it? I tried:

```
data new_data;
set existing_data;
 do i = 1 to 100;
  if i <= 50 then new_variable = 0;
  if i >= 51 then new_variable = 1;
 end;
run;
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep there is a way, use the SAS internal variable `_n_` for row number. Like this...

```
data new;
  set existing;
  if _n_<=50 then new_var=0;
  if _n_>50 then new_var=1;
run;
```

Comment: you can make it even simpler, `new_var = (_n_>50);`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out one way to do it.

```
data dummy;
do i = 1 to 50;
  new_variable = 0;
  output;
end;
do i = 1 to 50;
  new_variable = 1;
  output;
end;
run;

data new_data;
  merge existing_data dummy;
run;
```

Is there a way to do it all in one go?